# Balance board with Arduino

Tags: voltage-measurement

We're trying to build a rudimentary Balance Board using four force sensitive resistors and an Arduino unit, but are not sure how to wire up the circuit.

How do we connect the sensors to the Arduino?

Comment: What is a "Balance Board" in this context?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Balance_Board

Answer (score 5):

Lady Ada has a tutorial on using force sensitive resistors with the Arduino:

http://www.ladyada.net/learn/sensors/fsr.html

She also has quite a few other useful tutorials to get you started on many things Arduino and electronic.

Answer (score 4):

You have given very little detail which means my answer is going to have to have very little detail as well.

If you have a resistance that changes based off of force being applied to it, I would recommend creating a voltage divider with the resistor. I would then have the microcontroller compute an A/D. This analog voltage will be related to the pressure that is being applied.